# Exporting an application from XCode for IOS

Tags: xcode

I tried an Xcode app which was created on Unity 3D but got this error:

> sampling->cvTextureCacheTexture = CreateTextureFromCVTextureCache(sampling->cvTextureCache, cvImageBuffer, w, h, GL_BGRA_EXT, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE);

[image: errors]

Comment: So fix the error! `GL_BGRA_EXT` needs to be declared...

Comment: Please post your code and the corresponding errors instead of images.